# How to Sign a Pdf using a CSR and private key via Python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, digital-signature, x509certificate, csr

Have been trying to find any python library or any example of code that let's me implement this Certificate on an existing pdf as a Digital Signature which will be accompanied by another Signature from other provider but they use an API to put their signature to the PDF.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A CSR is a *certificate signing request*, isn't it? At least that's what the tag [tag:csr] says. For signing a PDF you need a finished certificate that already is signed by its issuer...

Comment: @mkl Thanks for the help i'm currently looking into it, just got this csr and the private key and my boss told me to sign any pdf that we generate with it, like no orientation and no idea from my scrum master as well so i just tried to work with it, didn't thought i needed to generate said certificate from the CSR, so thank you again.